# having problems lining up a few objects on my form

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I'm having problems getting my buttons to line up. Here is what they are going:

[image]

This is what I'd like them to do:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Logon2", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
  { 
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">  
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field focus">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "GenericTextBox", onkeyup = "enableLogonButton()" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "GenericPasswordBox", onkeyup = "enableLogonButton()" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
          <br/>

            <p>
              <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Log On" onclick="DisableSubmitButton()"/>        
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?sealID=HWXeUzAbOxyxKnb28ueDib8UFmw5ek2tyWQ6mXXt6Q06AQAlQrAtpBz"></script>
            </p>        

          <p>
            If you need to retrieve your username @Html.ActionLink("click here.", "ForgotUsername", "Account")<br/>
            If you need to reset your password @Html.ActionLink("click here.", "ForgotPassword", "Account")
          </p>

        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

I'm not even sure how to get them to show up even with each other.

Any suggestions?

Comment: using chrome, i just r click the element -> inspect element and play whit css until i found what's wrong, then aplay it to css. as a start u may want to warp them separated and try a float left on the submit?

Comment: Please can you add a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a class name "get_in_middle" to p tag which holds both login and image.
then place this css,

```
p.get_in_middle input,p.get_in_middle img{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TUGup/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try to look in chrome element inspector, what type of object is loaded from Godaddy. it will have some class or ID and then create rule with this class or Id name in your CSS file:

```
.class-of-godaddy-element {
   position:relative;
   top: 5px; //this may be change according to your style
}
```

Check this out, I made same example on JS Fiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/TUGup/7/

Comment: Because of, Godaddy button is loading after Dom Ready state, CSS is not applying to it, so I used simple jQuery to change it's css properties after loading.

you can use any different framework or pure Javascript, to achieve same effect.

Answer (score 0):

in chrome u can "live" edit ur css, just by rigth click on the element and go to "inspect element"

ill do somthing like:

```
     <div style="
float: left;
margin-top: 3px;
margin-right: 10px;
      ">
          <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Log On" onclick="DisableSubmitButton()"/>        
    </div>
    <div>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?sealID=HWXeUzAbOxyxKnb28ueDib8UFmw5ek2tyWQ6mXXt6Q06AQAlQrAtpBz"></script>
    </div>
```

dont know how your layout css is but it shuld give u a basic idea

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what the GoDaddy Javascript outputs, you may need only this CSS:

```
input[value='Log On'] {vertical-align:17px}
```

and you won't need to adjust your HTML, or try to figure out the class names the GoDaddy seal uses.